# Cannot Edit CiviCRM Profile via Drupal

Tags: drupal, profile, editor

I have created a CiviCRM Profile called "Edit Details" i have checked:

- View/Edit Drupal User Account
- Standalone Form or Directory

It Displays correctly with no issues however when i go to edit it nothing happens, it does not add in the fields.

This is me trying to edit it as a Administrator so all the permissions are enabled.

Another thing i realised when saving the page it removes my Drupal Roles which is really weird. This is only when doing this with the CiviCRM profile.

Is there another way i can put CiviCRM fields onto the Drupal Edit page other than profiles.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there another way? Yes (not necessarily a great way)

1/ make a Webform-civicrm form, and set it to work as a a block showing on user/* and user.

2/ make a View showing the data in a block on /user with an Edit linking going to a webform.

That said, I have never seen a Profile not work in the way you are describing so it sounds as if something else is tripping you up.

Comment: Not sure why the profile doesnt save the changes. The permissions are set correctly. So i am really confused. I will try the webform idea and see if it works.

Comment: Webforms worked! Thanks